# Congratulations Screen on Android

Tags: android

I have a quiz app . when a user scores 90% and above the congratulation screen will be displayed. My question is i want the background of the screen to have small and different coloured paper like objects falling creating a illusion that i am congratulating him.

Please help me how to implement this idea.

Comment: you can use animation.

Comment: can you please elaborate what kind of animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animation to to show falling color objects. You can follow this link to view of this type of animation:-

[Frame By Frame Animation](http://androidexample.com/Frame_By_Frame_Animation_%7C_2D_Animation_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=104&aaid=126)

Comment: will look into the link and reply back to you vaibhav.

Comment: This link will work in my case.thanks for the link.